# Get CheckedItems from a form to a UserControl vb

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls, checkboxlist

I have a Form(name = FrmIndicateurs) which contains a CheckListBox (name = ClbOrga) and a Usercontrol

In my UserControl i have a button (name = button2) that need to do something for each checkeditems in the ClbOrga

the problem is that is seems to create a new instance of the Checklistbox instead of getting the current Checklistbox

i'm quite new to programming so i'm sorry if it is a "basic"
Do you have a solution ?

(visual studio 2008)

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim message As String = "Etes vous sûr ?"
    Dim reponse As MsgBoxResult
    Dim style As MsgBoxStyle
    style = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo
    reponse = MsgBox(message, style, "Validation")

    If reponse = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

        For Each orga As Communs.CLBItem In FrmIndicateurs.ClbOrga.CheckedItems

            Dim IdOrga As Integer
            Dim datao As New DataSet
            Dim requete2 As String = "SELECT IDOrganisation FROM Organisations WHERE Nom = @P1"
            Data.SqlExecute(datao, requete2, 1, Variables.DbcConnection, orga.Nom)
            For Each r As DataRow In datao.Tables(0).Rows

                IdOrga = CInt(r("IDOrganisation"))

            Next

            Dim IdIndicateur As Integer
            Dim Datai As New DataSet
            Dim requete1 As String = " SELECT IDIndicateur FROM Indicateurs WHERE Nom = @P1"
            Data.SqlExecute(Datai, requete1, 1, Variables.DbcConnection, Label4.Text)
            For Each r As DataRow In Datai.Tables(0).Rows

                IdIndicateur = CInt(r("IDIndicateur"))

            Next

            Dim Datar As New DataSet
            Dim requete As String = "DELETE FROM Valeurs WHERE IDOrganisation = @P2 AND IDIndicateur = @P1"

            Data.SqlExecute(Datar, requete, 2, Variables.DbcConnection, IdIndicateur, IdOrga)
        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are not creating form instances (FrmIndicateurs as the class name and used in code), it can create a new form different from the one you see.  The new one would have nothing checked.